# Using Codesniffer with Xampp on Windows 7

Tags: xampp, phpcodesniffer

I'm running into an issue trying to get codesniffer working with Xampp (1.7.1).  I've got pear running by editing the include_path in php.ini.

When I try to run phpcs I get the following errors:

```
Warning: include_once(PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\phpcs on Line 31

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PHP/Codesniffer/CLI.php' for inclusion (include_path="\xampp\php\pear") in C:\xampp\php\phpcs on line 31

Fatal error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI' not found in C:\xampp\php\phpcs on line 34
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like the PHP include path is wrong, even though PEAR itself is working. It is a bit strange though.

Do you have a `\xampp\php\pear\PHP\CodeSniffer\CLI.php` file? If not, can you find where it is under the `\xampp\php\pear` directory?

If it is, for example, actually at `\xampp\php\pear\source\pear\PHP\CodeSniffer\CLI.php` then you'll need to change your include_path to be `\xampp\php\pear\source\pear`. But this could then break your PEAR install, which probably means PEAR is not configured correctly.

If this is the case, it's worth uninstalling PHP_CodeSniffer, changing the location of PEAR's php_dir configuration variable, and then reinstalling PHP_CodeSniffer.

For example:

```
pear uninstall php_codesniffer
pear config-set php_dir \xampp\php\pear
pear install php_codesniffer
```

(sorry, I'm not sure if pear on windows requires the drive letter in the path, so just check the current value using `pear config-get php_dir` and adjust the path based on that format.)

I hope that info helps you move forward a bit.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR might have also setup an include path in the phpcs executable (-d include_path="''") which is overriding the default. This is particularly annoying if you forget to create a default php.ini file until after phpcs is installed.